# Error "Picklist value is not supported" when deploying Path

Tags: community, deployment, sales-process, path

When deploying a Path based on the Stage picklist for the Opportunity object I got this error:

> Picklist value is not supported

Answer (score 0):

### **The solution for me was the following:**

The issue was that my Sales Process for this particular opportunity record type was corrupted or something, I know this because when I tried to edit the Sales Process I got a Salesforce "server internal error 500". I recreated the Sales Process for this Opportunity record type and was able to deploy the related path without an issue.

**I think the general gist here is that** your path references a picklist field value that is not available to the record type for which you want to deploy the path, in my case this issue was caused by a corrupted Sales Process.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a new picklist value. As picklist values does not updating during deployment of package, had to add this manually to prod/sandbox.